# Value not passing to the controller from ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

Here I want to pass the value which am getting in data to the controller so I gave my code like this.

```
$("#sup_box").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toPost = $('.row_selected input').serialize();
    alert(toPost);
    $('.submit_data').text(toPost);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>app/admin_control/add_data",
        data: toPost,
        dataType:"text",
        success: function (data) {
          alert("hai");
     },
        error: function (data) {
     alert("not");
  }
    });
});
```

My controller looks like this .

```
 public function add_data()
    {

      $bill_no = '000';
      $data = $_POST['data'];
      var_dump($data);
      $data1 = json_decode($data,true);
      var_dump($data1);
     foreach($data1 as $r) {
       $data = array('user_id'=>1,'bill_no'=>$bill_no);
       $this->Admin_model->add_data($data);

 }
}
```

But when I pass into the controller am getting error like `undefined index data` in console

My `toPost` variable contains value like this

```
add_type%5B%5D=super&add_number%5B%5D=324&add_quantity%5B%5D=44&add_amount%5B%5D=440.00&add_checkbox=1&add_profit%5B%5D=440.00&add_agent_amount%5B%5D=0.00
```

Comment: The first assumption is that there is nothing with key 'data' in `$_POST['data']`. I would check that variable, what it contains and where something like `'data' : 'someValue'` is added to that object/variable/array whatever it is.

Comment: @john `topost` contains values

Comment: not sure that's enough; the json that you send should look like `{"data" : "SomeValue_1234_etc", <everything else> }` . There should be a property called `data` among all the others.

Comment: you should always use isset to check if the post data exists or use the input class of ci e.g. $this->input->post('data'); however that is just good practice. is your var dump giving you anything? print here what the actual value of $data looks like and what you are expecting

Comment: i just changed my data type to `text` an i will paste the content comes in `topost`

Comment: datatype only effects the incoming response, not the outgoing input for controller. if you are returning json that it should be json

Comment: i had pasted my `toPost` values please have a look

Comment: ah i get it, you can't access data because there is no data key in your values. for example you could access `$_POST['add_type']` because it exists. to see all values that are posting you can do `print_r($_POST);` ... I'm also unsure what you are trying to accomplish next, none of your inputs seem to be used. Why are you using json_decode? this isn't json encoded data. just a raw post stream...

Comment: next level i will be using post values of  `$_POST['add_type']` but before that i need to get all the values in the controller so only i can use that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165616/discussion-between-alex-and-user-777).

Comment: @user_777 add your form code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization basically does this:

```
data: {
    'field_name_1': 'field_value_1',
    'field_name_2': 'field_value_2',
}
```

and this: `field_name_1=field_value_1&field_name_2=field_value_2`

Instead of you having to manually build that ^ it does it for you. So the only variables that exist via post become `$_POST['field_name_1']` and `$_POST['field_name_2']`. You can confirm via `print_r($_POST);` to see what post keys exist.

---

You need to get your `row_selected` into an object that we can turn into an array in php:

```
    $("#sup_box").on("submit", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var objs = [];
        $('.row_selected').each(function () {
            var inputs = $(this).find('input'), arr = {};
            inputs.each(function () {
                arr[$(this).attr('id')] = this.value;
            });
            objs.push(arr);
        });
        console.log(objs);
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>app/admin_control/add_data",
            data: JSON.stringify(objs),
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("hai");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //alert("not");
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
$stream = $this->input->raw_input_stream;
$postdata = json_decode($stream);
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($postdata);

foreach ($postdata as $item) {
    $data = array(
        'bill_no' => '1',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'type' => $item->add_type,
        'number' => $item->add_number,
        'quantity' => $item->add_quantity,
        'amount' => $item->add_amount,
        'profit' => $item->add_profit,
        'agent_amount' => $item->add_agent_amount
    );
    $this->db->insert('sometable', $data);
    //print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If submit_data referred here is a form field

```
$('.submit_data').text(toPost);
```

Try to get data by

```
$data = $_POST['submit_data'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes,

You should use `console.log(toPost)` while checking in ajax codes.

Also in the PHP controller section you can use `print_r($_POST)` or `dd($_POST)`. This will help you to find which `$_POST[]` array key to look for.

Answer (score 0):

**In AJAX**

```
$("#sup_box").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toPost = $('#sup_box').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/app/admin_control/add_data",
        data: toPost,
        # dataType:"json", if need
        success: function (data) {
            alert("hai");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("not");
        }
    });
});
```

**In PHP**

```
$type = $_POST["add_type"];
....
```

**In Form**

```
<form id="sup_box"></form>
```